# VS code doesn't highlight changed/added lines after moving the repo's folder

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-code

I decided to reorganize my folder structure inside the folder with my repos. After moving my repo's folder to another place, VS code stopped highlighting changed/added lines as well as stopped showing places where lines were removed. You can see the way it does it on the picture below.

[image]

When I try using source control in the folder I see the following message:

[image]

> The folder currently open doesn't have a git repository. You can initialize a repository which will enable source control features powered by git.

Although, command-line `git` does understand that this is my repo and does track the changes and sees the entire commit history.

I tried googling but found nothing. Please help.

Comment: The fact that it works OK from the command line points to a VS issue, although what that issue is, I have no idea. The fact that restarting fixed it suggests maybe some sort of bad interaction with some antivirus software or something along those lines (although those often break command-line Git too).

Answer (score 3):

I decided to commit and push the changes, remove the repo, and clone it again. But it didn't help. I was still seeing the message in the `source control` page.

Interestingly, **restarting my computer solved the issue.**